# CLI Error: "The Sitecore Management Service version of the environment this Sitecore CLI operates with is outdated"

Tags: sitecore-cli

There is `Sitecore 10.2` solution running with CLI tool `v4.2`. In order to upgrade to `CLI v5.1` the following steps were done:

1. In `sitecore.json` all the plugin versions have been updated:

   ```
   "plugins": [
     "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization@5.1.25",
     "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing@5.1.25",
     "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Indexing@5.1.25",
     "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.ResourcePackage@5.1.25",
     "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Database@5.1.25"
   ],
   ```
2. In the `.env` file, the MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE version has been updated:

   ```
   MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE=scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/sitecore-management-services-xm1-assets:5.1-1809
   ```

Containers have been rebuilt with `--no-cache` option. But there is still a version conflict. The CLI error:

```
The Sitecore Management Service version of the environment this Sitecore CLI operates with is outdated, please update the Sitecore Management Service to version 5.1.25.
```

Locally, it can be mitigated via [unrecommended setting](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/version-compatibility.html) in `sitecore.json`, but the error still appears on build agents where we build/install serialization packages:

```
"settings": {
  "versionComparingEnabled": false
}
```

What causes this version conflict?

Comment: Are you able to determine the version of the management service running in the container?

Comment: downloaded `Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.dll` from a running CM instance. Version is `5.1.25` (that is an assembly ftom the Management Services package)

Comment: Have you tried deleting any of the packages from the .sitecore/package-cache folder that do not match 5.1.25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the same as an issue I bumped into when upgrading the CLI/`Sitecore Management Service 5.1.25` in a solution using `Sitecore Headless Rendering 20.0.0` on `XP 10.2`

There are a few assemblies that crossover between the two asset images (e.g. Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.dll). Applying the asset image to the CM for `Sitecore Management Service 5.1.25` before the asset image for `Sitecore Headless Rendering 20.0.0`, results in the latter's assemblies being used.  However the assemblies from `Sitecore Headless Rendering 20.0.0` do not support the GQL headers required to support the `versionComparingEnabled` flag used in `CLI v5.1.25`.

`Headless services 20.0.2` was released to support this and appropriate images have been pushed to the Sitecore Container Registry. Assuming you are currently using Sitecore Headless Rendering 20.0.0 (or 20.0.1), then upgrading your solution to use the 20.0.2 tags should resolve this issue.  The release notes for 20.0.2 can be found here:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Headless%20Rendering/20x/Sitecore%20Headless%20Rendering%202002/Release%20Notes

Unfortunately this incompatibility is not currently noted in the CLI 5.x upgrade documentation.

Comment: I have updated to 20.0.2, but I am periodically still seeing the InternalServerError. It looks like it is hitting a request queue limit. It now periodically works, so it's an improvement, but I'm wondering if I am still missing something.